# angular service unit test DoneFn

Tags: angular, unit-testing

I'm following the angular official doc and I can see this code:

```
it("#getObservableValue should return value from observable", (done: DoneFn) => {
    service.getObservableValue().subscribe(value => {
      expect(value).toBe("observable value");
      done();
    });
  });
```

I'm wondering where DoneFn comes from because I've no error either import for the typing.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you follow the Interface definition you will see that it is under:

`node_modules/@types/jasmine/index.d.ts`

```
/** Action method that should be called when the async work is complete */
interface DoneFn extends Function {
    (): void;

    /** fails the spec and indicates that it has completed. If the message is an Error, Error.message is used */
    fail: (message?: Error | string) => void;
}
```

You don't need to import or use it, it's mostly for reference. I am not sure how `@types` exactly work but I suppose if there is a `@types` typing within the project, node knows how to find the definition as they are all indexed in this one folder.

**UPDATE:**

I found out this is being configured by `tsconfig.json`

```
"typeRoots": [
  "node_modules/@types"
],
```

Comment: thanks for the replay may be its because interface DoneFn extends Function extends. Function is a native object

Comment: Yeah but usually you still have to import custom interfaces. I guess node typings work a little different. There are also global interfaces for web api stuff (e.g. `Event`) and when you follow them, they will lead you to some typings file. (`<...>.d.ts`). Javascript does not know interfaces. In my case (VSCode) there is internal libs with typings for most stuff like Web API, the things such as `DoneFn` exist on a project level

Comment: @user3887366 I found out where this is defined and updated the anwer :)

Comment: Why do we need **DonFn** in this test case? I ran the same test case without DoneFn its worked by saying 'SPEC  HAS NO EXPECTATION'